# What does "look what the wind blew in" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, definition

From the movie Masterminds (2016)

In the beggining the main character is saying about the story of his life.

> In 1997, I was a quiet middle-aged man knocking on 40. But then, then
>   the wind blew in Miss Kelly Campbell.

Searching the Internet I learned that "look what the wind blew in" probably has the same meaning as "look what the cat dragged in" which a one says when someone that is disliked shows up. But in the movie the main character's saying the phrase about "the wind" blandly, like he actually was glad that Miss Kelly Campbell showed up in his life.

My question is - does the phtase mean only something or someone unpleasant or it has more neutral nature, like "But then she showed up"

Comment: It's an allusion to idiomatic [***winds of change***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/winds-of-change) *(actions or influences that will lead to important political **or social changes**)*, and the informal/sarcastic *Look what the wind's blown in!* (said dismissively/insultingly when someone considered insignificant arrives unexpectedly). You can understand ***the wind*** in your example as ***Fate*** (personified).

Comment: These phrases are also used jokingly among friends and family, where the family member or friend who is arriving is not disliked, but there can be a sense that the visit is long overdue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This phrase means something happened unexpectedly. There is no implication of unpleasantness.